# progress bar animate with slider slides

Tags: jquery, slider, progress-bar

Hi Guys I need your help I am creating a testimonial slider and i need a progress bar with slider i created both things but problem is progress bar just working once but i want when new slide comes then progress bar have to restart.

Here is My code:

```
<div class="testimonial">
        <div class="test">1</div>
        <div class="test">2</div>
        <div class="test">3</div>
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS
.testimonial {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.testimonial .test {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
.testimonial .bar{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 4px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #e1e1e1;
 top:120px;

}
.testimonial .bar .progress{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-radius: 4px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 0;
 background: #000;  
}
here is jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
            // settings
            var $slider = $('.testimonial'); // class or id of carousel slider
            var $slide = 'div.test'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
            var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
            var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

            function classAnimate(){
                $( ".progress" ).animate({
                    width: "100%"
                }, 5500);

            }
            classAnimate();
            function slides(){
              return $slider.find($slide);
            }

            slides().fadeOut();

            // set active classes
            slides().first() .addClass('active') ;
            slides().first() .fadeIn($transition_time);

            // auto scroll 
            $interval = setInterval(
                    function () {
                        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

                        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
                        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

                        if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1;

                        // loop to start


                        slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
                        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
                        classAnimate((slides().length));

                    }
                    , $transition_time + $time_between_slides
            );




        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should reset jquery animation each time.

```
function classAnimate(){
            $( ".progress" )
            .clearQueue()
            .stop()
            .css(
                {width:'0%'}
            )
            .animate({
                width: "100%"
            }, 5500);

        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yp8L2t9h/